# BigQuery tables.insert 404 Error

Tags: google-bigquery

In the BigQuery documents it says that tables.insert creates a new empty table (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/insert)

But when I try to test that endpoint within the page I get a 404 Table not found error.

**Request:**

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/myProject/datasets/temp/tables?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "expirationTime": "1452627594",
 "tableReference": {
  "tableId": "myTable"
 }
}
```

**Response:**

```
404 OK

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not found: Table myProject.myTable"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not found: Table myProject:temp.myTable"
 }
}
```

I am sure there is a reasonable explanation of the 404 error but I couldn't understood it since I am trying to create that table, it should be ok if doesn't exist yet?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Info you provided in Request Body is not enough for BigQuery to create new table

At least - add schema - something like below (just as an example):

```
{
 "schema": {
  "fields": [
   {
    "name": "page_event",
    "mode": "repeated",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "fields": [
     {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "STRING"
     },
     {
      "name": "description",
      "type": "STRING"
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

See more in [Tables resource](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#resource) for what you can supply in Request Body

Below is an example with above dummy schema that should work:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/myProject/datasets/temp/tables?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "schema": {
  "fields": [
   {
    "name": "page_event",
    "mode": "repeated",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "fields": [
     {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "STRING"
     },
     {
      "name": "description",
      "type": "STRING"
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 },
 "expirationTime": "1452560523000",
 "tableReference": {
  "tableId": "myTable"
 }
}
```

> EDIT:

And the reason why it didn't worked with  `"expirationTime": "1452627594"` from your question is because it points to the past

Comment: Tried it with https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/insert ,  still getting "message": "Not found: Table myProject:temp.myTable"

Also I've checked further required parameters at Tables resource. I am not sure if I understood correctly but for example parameter "externalDataConfiguration.sourceFormat" is flagged as "Required" but I don't want any externalDataConfiguration, all I want is an empty table with an expiration date. 

Thanks anyway, I'll keep trying until it works.

Comment: Above examples just worked for me with no any issue. Try to see what you can do differently. I assume you actually have those ProjectID and DatasetID you use

Comment: see correction in my answer - remove your expiration time and it will work - i actually didnt check correctness of provided number for it and just copied from your question

Comment: So, is it possible to create an empty table with an expirationTime? If I add that parameter it gives 404. If I ran a "Patch" or "Update" handler after adding the table as you've instructed,  table is gone from BigQuery UI, weird.

Comment: 1. yes - i was able to create schema-empty table (never did/used this before) 2. in any case patch allows you to patch schema (for example) without re-writing table. 3. make sure you provide proper expiration time (or even skip it for now) and i think it is just better to provide schema on first creation