# how to set table expiry time big query

Tags: python-2.7, api, google-bigquery

Need help in setting expiry time for a new table in GBQ.

I am creating/uploading a new file as a table in gbq using the below code,

```
 def uploadCsvToGbq(self, table_name, jsonSchema, csvFile, delim):
    job_data = {
        'jobReference': {
            'projectId': self.project_id,
            'job_id': str(uuid.uuid4())
        },
        #"expires":str(datetime.now()+timedelta(seconds=60)),
        #"expirationTime": 20000,
        #"defaultTableExpirationMs":20000,
        'configuration': {
            'load': {'writeDisposition': 'WRITE_TRUNCATE',
                     'fieldDelimiter': delim,
                     'skipLeadingRows': 1,
                     'sourceFormat': 'CSV',
                     'schema': {
                         'fields': jsonSchema
                     },
                     'destinationTable': {
                         'projectId': self.project_id,
                         'datasetId': self.dataset_id,
                         'tableId': table_name
                     }
                     }
        }
    }

    upload = MediaFileUpload(csvFile,
                             mimetype='application/octet-stream', chunksize=1048576,
                             # This enables resumable uploads.
                             resumable=True)
    start = time.time()
    job_id = 'job_%d' % start
    # Create the job.
    return self.bigquery.jobs().insert(projectId=self.project_id,
                                       body=job_data,
                                       media_body=upload).execute()
```

This is a perfect code that uploads that file into GBQ as a new table,now i need to set the expiry time for the table,already i tried setting(which is commented) expires,expirationTime and defaultTableExpirationMs,but nothing works.

Do anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou both,I combined both solution,but made some modifications to work for mine.
As i am creating the table by uploading csv, i am setting the expirationTime by calling patch method and passing tableid to that,

```
def createTableWithExpire(bigquery, dataset_id, table_id, expiration_time):
"""
    Creates a BQ table that will be expired in specified time.

    Expiration time can be in Unix timestamp format e.g. 1452627594
"""    
    table_data = {
        "expirationTime": expiration_time,
    }
    return bigquery.tables().patch(
        projectId=_PROJECT_ID,
        datasetId=dataset_id,
        tableId=table_id,
        body=table_data).execute()
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [Tables: patch API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/patch) and set [expirationTime](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#expirationTime) property

Answer (score 1):

Below function creates a table with an expirationTime, so as an alternative solution you can create the table first and insert the data later.

```
def createTableWithExpire(bigquery, dataset_id, table_id, expiration_time):
    """
        Creates a BQ table that will be expired in specified time.

        Expiration time can be in Unix timestamp format e.g. 1452627594
    """    
        table_data = {
            "expirationTime": expiration_time,
            "tableReference":
                {
                    "tableId": table_id
                }
        }
        return bigquery.tables().insert(
            projectId=_PROJECT_ID,
            datasetId=dataset_id,
            body=table_data).execute()
```

Also answered by Mikhail in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730159/bigquery-tables-insert-404-error) SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to set the expiration time after the table has been created:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import datetime 
client    = bigquery.Client()
table_ref = client.dataset('my-dataset').table('my-table') # get table ref
table     = client.get_table(table_ref) # get Table object

# set datetime of expiration, must be a datetime type
table.expires = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today() +  
                                          datetime.timedelta(days=2),
                                          datetime.time() )
table = client.update_table(table, ['expires']) # update table
```